# How to Group Claims to be Used for AspNetUserClaims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294616) book and it talks about using claims and roles are for more legacy. One thing it does not seem to talk about is how to store these claims.

Say I have these claims.

```
canRead
canWrite
CanUpdate
CanDelete
```

Now I have 2 types of "roles" admin(should have all these claims) and user(should just have canRead).

Should I make a new table(or hijack the roles tables...which from book seems like if you use AspNetUserClaims you won't use the role tables) in my database that stores these claims? Or in my service layer?

For instance a new user is being created and in my front end, I want to give the user a choice to make this person and "admin" or "user". Should I have something like this

```
public Claim {
   public string ClaimType { get; set; }
   public string ClaimValue { get; set; }  
}

//somewhere in a service file.
List<Claim> allClaims = new List<Claim>(){
    new Claim() {
        ClaimType: "Permission",
        ClaimValue: "canRead",
    },
     new Claim() {
        ClaimType: "Permission",
        ClaimValue: "canWrite",
    },
     new Claim() {
        ClaimType: "Permission",
        ClaimValue: "canUpdate",
    },
     new Claim() {
        ClaimType: "Permission",
        ClaimValue: "canDelete",
    }
}

var groupedClaims = Dictionary<string,List<Claim>>()
groupedClaims.add("admin", allClaims);
groupedClaims.add("user", [only some of the claims]);

// then when need to create new user grab right group claims and insert into AspNetUserClaims
```

Answer (score 0):

You're still thinking of roles, so you're trying to group the claims in groups that are like roles. You don't need to do that, although there is nothing wrong with it if it satisfies your project's requirements.

Without the roles (or groups), you would have a table for the user's claims. When the admin adds a new user to the system, they assign the claims (or permissions) to the user directly one by one.

With the roles (or groups), you have two choices.

1) Virtual roles: In this case, no need for any additional data table. When the admin adds a new user to the system, they assign the role(s) to the user. The system will then add the claims associated with each role to the user. So you're using the roles just as an easy way to assign groups of claims to the users without the admin having to click one by one.

2) Real roles: In this case, you need an additional data table for the user's role(s). When the admin adds a new user to the system, they assign the role(s) to the user. When the user logs in, the system will then load the claims associated with each user role.

Comment: Well right now the requirement is more in the terms of roles as this is what the customer is thinking in, you assign this role to user A and they can do everything that that role allows. They don't want to be able to go down to allow checking each box one at a time. I am just trying to build it so that when they decide one day done the road to change it to that basically can just rewrite the interface from a dropdown to checkboxes. So if I understand what you wrote right I essentially need  Option 1.  Though I don't know what you mean by no additional data tables required.

Comment: Also even if I did it the way of the user checks each box to determine the user claims" that list has to come from somewhere either from some file or in the database and that is one of the things I am wondering what people do? Json file? just in C# or database table.

Comment: Yes, I recommend Option 1. By data table I meant the table that you use store the user data. For Option 1, you need a table to store the user's claims, but no need for a table to store the user's roles. For Option 2, you need a table for user's claims and another table for user's roles. As for your second question, I would store them in the database (I call those Lists Tables, while the ones above Data Tables). For Option 1, you will need a Roles table, a Claims table, and a Role_Claims table for the association. Use these tables to build your UI and logic.

Comment: But I should not use AspNetRoles/AspNetRoleClaims table fot sore the claims and roles as that has a 1 to many relationship where I think I would need more to many to many.

Comment: Also when I am making a UserClaim for these permissions what do I use for ClaimType.    ClaimTypes.Authentication? So new Claim(   ClaimTypes.Authentication, "employee.add)

Comment: or new Claim( "employee.add", "")

Comment: Oh, I never use AspNet tables. I always create my own tables. As for your second question, you need a different type for each claim. You shouldn't have multiple claims for the same type like you did in your question. Think of the type as the claim ID. So for example: type=email, value=x@y.z and type=can_read, value=true. I would recommend using all small or all capital letters for the types.

Comment: Should I always put a value? I would have thought having a claim associated would be good enough? Also new Claim() for values takes a string so I would have to store the value as string.

Comment: I actually have something similar in use right now where I thought claims were the final solution but having a more than a dozen claims becomes overwhelming, so I reverted back to roles with claims.  As for the claims themselves I created a custom claim type and started populating claims `aircraft.update, aircraft.view, aircraft.create` for example with an `.org` claimType  `http:\\www.domaininquestion.org`, if you look at the db tables associated you will see ClaimTypes.Authentication default to a schema `.org`. Policies are then used to authorize access...

Comment: So you did not use "aircraft.update" as your claimtype? Seems like some people would make that claimtype but others not.

Comment: Claims are string only, so you'll have to cast the values. Create helper functions to use for the casting. It's up to you whether to have a value for Boolean claims or not, and code the Boolean helper function accordingly. The types are unique strings (like IDs), but otherwise can be anything you want. They don't have to be domains or domain-like. But domains guarantee their uniqueness if you integrate several systems together.

Comment: I am so confused as other articles are saying you should not use claims for what are essentially permissions(ie your can_read).  For instance https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Yes, authorization is pretty complex and really depends on each application on a case by case bases. Read the comments at the bottom of that article to get better understanding about what he called fine-grained vs. course-grained permissions. If you really want the most extensible and scalable solution, then follow his advice. However, many systems don't need that complexity. For example, there are systems that only need an admin role (and a "non-admin" role). Analyze your system requirement carefully and project the future to choose the best design. Using a complex design has a cost.